# How to convert a single char to a null-terminated const char*

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

I want to loop through a string of characters pull each one out and each one has to be of type `const char*` so I can pass it to a function. Here's an example.

```
string thestring = "abc123";

for(int i = 0; i < thestring.length(); i++){
    const char* theval = thestring[i]; // somehow convert this must be type const char*
    string result = func(theval);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: do you want to call the func() with "a", then "b" and so on? Why?  This question is hard to answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
string sym(1, thestring[i]);
theval = sym.c_str();
```

It gives a null-terminated const char* for every character.

Comment: Not your downvoter, but this does not answer the question OP actually asked.

Comment: this is exactly what i needed doing &thestring[i] gave results of abc123, bc123, c123, 123, 23, 3. This gave me each individual character thanks

Comment: OMG thank you so much. For some reason none of the other answers are working lol

Comment: Years later I needed this, thanks man. I have two function taking const char* (one took it and passed to another). for example if 'A' (by &) was passed it would end up in function as "Aiiiiiiiiiiiiiii\n"

Can u give more explanation on what it does?

Answer (score 28):

You can take the address of that element:

```
theval = &thestring[i];
```

Answer (score 6):

Usually a `const char *` is pointing to a full null-terminated string, not a single character, so I question if this is really what you want to do.

If it's really what you want, the answer is easy:

```
theval = &thestring[i];
```

If the function is really expecting a string but you want to pass it a string of a single character, a slightly different approach is called for:

```
char theval[2] = {0};
theval[0] = thestring[i];
result = func(theval);
```

Comment: Since he's already using strings, I'm guessing he's just looking for a pointer to char.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, it's obvious that the function requires a pointer to char but it's not obvious why. It's trivial to pass a single char as a parameter, so it's far more likely that the function takes in a pointer to a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that the `func` call is expecting a C-string as it's input. In which case you can do the following:

```
string theString = "abc123";
char tempCString[2];
string result;

tempCString[1] = '\0';

for( string::iterator it = theString.begin();
     it != theString.end(); ++it )
{
   tempCString[0] = *it;
   result = func( tempCString );
}
```

This will produce a small C-string (null terminated array of characters) which will be of length 1 for each iteration.

The `for` loop can be done with an index (as you wrote it) or with the iterators (as I wrote it) and it will have the same result; I prefer the iterator just for consistency with the rest of the STL.

Another problem here to note (although these may just be a result of generalizing the code) is that the `result` will be overwritten on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the address of that element:

**`theval = &thestring[i];`**

Comment: Could you please format your code by highlighting it and hitting Ctrl+K