# Why is the error "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*"?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ convert char to const char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437099/c-convert-char-to-const-char)

I have a code snippet:

```
string opposite(string c)
{
    if(c == (string) "\""){return "\"";}
    if(c == (string) "<"){return ">";}
    throw;
}

int load_end(int start, string code)
{
    //start is the begining of "header.h" or <header> in #load "header.h" or #load <header>
    //code is self explanitory
    //This function returns the end of "header.h" or <header> in #load "header.h" or #load

    string chr = " ";
    int e;
    string asdf = opposite(code[start]);
    for(int i = start; chr == asdf; i++)
    {
        e = i;
        chr = code[i];
    }
    return e;
}
```

At the line where where the word where 'asdf' is defined the error occurs; "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*" [-fpermissive]". Also another error occurs: "c:\mingw\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.tcc|214|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator]' [-fpermissive]|". These errors make no sense to me of how they were caused.

Comment: Are you using `std::string`, or your own? If it's `std::string`, you don't need to cast in `opposite`, as `c == "\""` and `c == "<"` will implicitly convert the latter arguments to a string to compare.

Comment: `&code[start]` will return a char and that is going to be stored on `string c`.... change `string c` to `char c`

Comment: All I get on [GCC 4.7.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2B8IRC$0) is `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` and `warning: 'e' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`. The first applies to `opposite`, where there is no `return` statement, and the second to the fact that the for loop might not execute, leaving `e` uninitialized.

Comment: @chris you're not the only one.

Comment: I feel there's something wrong with `&code[start]`. In C++11, I'm pretty sure the internal string must be null-terminated, but I don't think that's the case in C++03, which could lead to huge problems. I agree that a `char` argument would be better in this case, as only one character is compared to it. To those complaining about the argument passed in, though, `code[start]` is a `char`, so `&code[start]` is a `char *`, which can be used to initialize a string, but requires a null-terminated sequence of characters to do so, which means relying on the implementation of `string`.

Comment: The problem is caused by &code[start]. You are passing the address of the character at position "start" which is a char *. If you pass std::string(&code[start]) that might solve the problem.

Comment: @fatma.ekici, There is an implicit conversion from `(const) char *` to `std::string`. What you suggested is done for you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, as the compiler helpfully tells us, you are sending in an address of a character where the function opposite expects a string.

1. First let's address a few issues in your code, always make the function return something for the other cases, if the function has a return value.What does your opposite function return if both the if conditions fail, think about it.Maybe you could return a error string or a null string.That's always a neat coding style.
2. Second, and this is a more crucial point, why do you have the function opposite take in a string and return a string, when its actually taking in a character and returning one?
3. Other possible problems are that chr is uninitialized.What is the role of chr here?
   If you could rectify the above, and clarify a bit we can help you.

Comment: `chr` is default-initialized to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`string[index]` is returning a char and not a string

Take a look at the documentation : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/

Tried to fix it :

```
char opposite(const char c)
{
    if(c == '<')
    {
       return '>';
    }
    return c; // (c == '"') { return '"'; }
}

int load_end(int start, string code)
{
    //This function returns the end of "header.h" or <header> in #load "header.h" or #load <header>
    char chr = 0;

    for(int i = start; chr == opposite(code[start]); i++)
    {
        chr = code[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```