# Convert from IBuffer to const unsigned char in C++ (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I want to convert from C# to C++ and return buffer again to C#
How can I convert IBuffer to "const unsigned char *data" and again to IBuffer

```
Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ Decode(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ buff, int len, int frame_size, int decode_fec);

Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ MyApi::Decode(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ buff, int len, int frame_size, int decode_fec)
{

}
```

Comment: From looking at the docs, it looks like `DataReader` and `DataWriter` might work.

Comment: but i don't know how can i convert array<unsigned char>^ to const unsigned char *

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437099/c-convert-char-to-const-char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the contents of an IBuffer by querying for the [IBufferByteAccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface then accessing IBufferByteAccess::[Buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846268(v=vs.85).aspx) to get its contents as a byte *

```
IUnknown* pUnk = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(buff);
IBufferByteAccess* pBufferByteAccess = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(pBufferByteAccess);
byte *pbytes = nullptr;
hr = pBufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pbytes);
```

Comment: IBufferByteAccess is undefined, is there any namespace that i have to import?. and  no instance of overloaded function "IID_PPV_ARGS_Helper" matches the argument list. thank you so much

Comment: IBufferByteAccess is defined in the Robuffer.h header. Check the docs I linked. IID_PPV_ARGS is in  Objbase.h . This is standard COM stuff, not C++/Cx

Comment: hi again. i add #include <robuffer.h>
#include <objbase.h> and first problem was fixed. but for IID_PPV_ARGS_Helper still same problem.

Comment: i put & before pBufferByteAccess, and it was worked fine. thanks.