# C++/WinRT - How to get data from IBuffer

Tags: c++, uwp, hololens, c++-cx, c++-winrt

I am doing an Hololens project in C++/WinRT and I want to get usable data from an IBuffer, given by VertexPositions() of a SpatialSurfaceMesh.

I use this [project sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/HolographicSpatialMapping) as a reference, because it more or less does what I want (it takes the IBuffers of the meshes and renders them)
The difference in my project is that I want to get the positions of meshes, not render them.

The function they use to get data from IBuffer is `GetDataFromIBuffer`, which is :

```
template <typename t = byte>
    t* GetDataFromIBuffer(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ container)
    {
        if (container == nullptr)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        unsigned int bufferLength = container->Length;

        if (!(bufferLength > 0))
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        ComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknown = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(container);
        ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> spByteAccess;
        hr = pUnknown.As(&spByteAccess);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        byte* pRawData = nullptr;
        hr = spByteAccess->Buffer(&pRawData);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return reinterpret_cast<t*>(pRawData);
    }
```

However this is in C++/CX, and I need to use C++/WinRT. I tried to translate it (as it is said in [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/spatial-mapping-in-directx), which explains how to do it and is based on the same project sample)
But I can't make it work, here is how it is after translating it :

```
template <typename t = byte>
t* GetDataFromIBuffer(IBuffer container)
{
    if (container == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    unsigned int bufferLength = container.Length();

    if (!(bufferLength > 0))
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknown = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(&container);
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBufferByteAccess> spByteAccess;
    hr = pUnknown.As(&spByteAccess);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    byte* pRawData = nullptr;
    hr = spByteAccess->Buffer(&pRawData);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return reinterpret_cast<t*>(pRawData);
}
```

The error is `Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF985543848 (ntdll.dll) in Project.exe: RangeChecks instrumentation code detected an out of range array access.`

It happens at the line `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknown = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(&container);`, more explicitely during the conversion from the `IUnknown` return by the reinterpret_cast to `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IUnknown>`.

I found no way to make this work.

I am really stuck here, do you have any ideas ? Thank you !

I also found a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538999/convert-from-ibuffer-to-const-unsigned-char-in-c-winrt) asking a somewhat similar question, but when I tried to do what the accepted answer gives :

```
byte* GetDataFromIBuffer(IBuffer container)
{
    if (container == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    unsigned int bufferLength = container.Length();

    if (!(bufferLength > 0))
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    IUnknown* pUnk = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(&container);
    Windows::Storage::Streams::IBufferByteAccess * spByteAccess = nullptr;
    hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spByteAccess));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    byte* pRawData = nullptr;
    hr = spByteAccess->Buffer(&pRawData);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return reinterpret_cast<byte*>(pRawData);
}
```

I have the exact same error, but this time on the line : 'hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spByteAccess));'

EDIT (after IInspectable answer):

I don't have errors anymore, so thanks for that !
However, the result I get are incoherent, I don't get logical positions in space.
What I do after getting the data from the IBuffer :

```
auto position = surfaceMesh.second->VertexPositions();
auto stride = position.Stride();
auto scale = surfaceMesh.second->VertexPositionScale();
auto positionCoordinateSystem = surfaceMesh.second->CoordinateSystem();

auto transform = positionCoordinateSystem.TryGetTransformTo(currentCoordinateSystem).Value();

...
// In a loop :

auto rawData = GetDataFromIBuffer(position.Data());

float x = BytesToShort(rawData + i) / scale.x;
i += stride;
float y = BytesToShort(rawData + i) / scale.y;
i += stride;
float z = BytesToShort(rawData + i) / scale.z;
i += stride * 2;

float3 vertex = MultVectByMat({ x, y, z }, transform);
```

Here are some of the results :
[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ48G.png)

It doesn't make sense to have z = 5 as it would mean the device detects a surface 5m behind itself

Comment: Have you tried the regular way - creating a `DataReader`? Like: ```using (var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(theBuffer)) { dataReader.ReadBytes...}``` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are well-hidden [extension functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer#cwinrt-extension-functions) to the `IBuffer` interface for the C++/WinRT projection, that aren't otherwise (to my knowledge) documented.

They live a special life in, in that they get [injected](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/c3b7fcfc9910e8eb87b02ba0e4356f123a327c44/cppwinrt/code_writers.h#L1277-L1514) by the `cppwinrt.exe` code generator, on the fly, and don't have any machine-readable representation (in metadata, or otherwise) to support automated documentation generation.

The one of specific interest is [`data()`](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/c3b7fcfc9910e8eb87b02ba0e4356f123a327c44/cppwinrt/code_writers.h#L1305-L1315):

> ```cpp
> uint8_t* data() const;
> ```

This would allow you to rewrite `GetDataFromIBuffer` as

```cpp
byte* GetDataFromIBuffer(IBuffer container)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<byte*>(container ? container.data() : nullptr);
}
```

Internally, it does essentially the same thing you were trying to do. I *think* the issue in your implementation is

```cpp
IUnknown* pUnk = reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(&container);
```

This reinterprets the address of a [`com_ptr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr) as if it were a COM pointer. A `com_ptr`, however, is a struct that contains a COM pointer (as opposed to deriving from it)<sup>1</sup>.

Applying the `reinterpret_cast` to the expression `container.`[`get()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr#com_ptrget-function) might work, but a better solution would be:

```cpp
auto const unk = container.as<IUnknown>();
```

In case `container` derives from multiple interfaces, the [`as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr#com_ptras-function) function template picks the canonical `IUnknown`.

As long as you're using the C++/WinRT-supplied extension function `data()`, you don't have to worry about any of those intricacies.

---

<sup>1</sup> *WRL's [`ComPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class) is modeled pretty much the same way, so the `reinterpret_cast` in the WRL-based implementation runs into the same UB (which may or may not result in the same observable behavior).*

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer ! It was well explained and clarified a lot

Now what I want is to get usable positions in floats, what I think I should do is to convert the bytes in short (as the format of VertexPosition is 2 bytes) and apply the scale/transform to the good system coordinate, does it seem good to you ? The results however seem incoherent

Comment: @Nikow Does this solve your immediate issue? If not, could you [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76046126/edit) your question with details about the error?

Comment: @Nikow I don't have enough information to comment on that. If my proposed solution solves your issue of getting a pointer to the raw `byte`s stored in the `IBuffer`, then that puts you in a good position to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on this particular issue.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks ! EDIT : Okay, I will ask another question, thanks again !

Comment: @Nikow The edit seems to confirm that the suggested changes work. If you know that your `IBuffer` holds a sequence of `VertexPosition`s you could try this: `auto GetVPFromIBuffer(IBuffer const& container) { return reinterpret_cast<VertexPosition const*>(container.data()); }`. Make sure to understand that [`IBuffer::Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer.length) returns the size in bytes, so you'd have to divide it by `sizeof(VertexPosition)` to get the element count.